# Making rounded corner boxes in html

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I'm making a rounded box (white inside) by creating a 3x3 table with the content in the middle cell, and inserting the images into the outer cells as I already have images of the table borders. However when I do this, the corner images come out right, but the top, left, right and bottom images come out really tiny. I haven't specified any sizes or measurements for anything. Is there anyway to make them come out properly?

Edit: Worked using corner images inserted with img src and the top/l/r/bottom images used as backgrounds.

Comment: You must post you code, otherwise there is no way anyone can help.

Comment: Oh, and: sure you want to use images to construct round corners on a box ? That is so 80ish... Why not do that with css ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - set the height and the width of the image to the requested size or if you are using background-images use CSS3's background-size and set it right but then - when using CSS3 anyways - you might as well just use border-radius and save a lot of work :)